# Populate data with underlying geology in Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo, geology

How do I add geology from polygons from a tab file (vector geology map) to a geochemical point data tab file, both in Mapinfo?

If I can add the underlying geology to the geochemistry file then I can interpret the geochemistry based on the geology.

Comment: If you have point geochemistry data then why you don't want to create grid that represents you some geochemistry indicator? After that you can study both geology and geochemistry representation as two layers in Mapinfo. But making grids is another matter.

Comment: Thanks @Vadym but I need one table file to determine the background geochemistry of each rock type, and for studying in ioGAS statistical software.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your point table with attributes from the geology polygon table using `Table > Update Column`. Once there, select the table and column to update (perhaps a new column you've added to hold the geology type?) and the source table (geology polygons table) and click the `Join...` button. There you can select the join to be `where object from <geochemical_points> is within object from <geology_polygons>`. Click OK to set the join and finally add the column from the polygon table that you want to source the data from.

Comment: Thanks, this works insofar as I have now copied the (geology) polygon ID to a new column in the geochemical point data file. But, I can't find a way to attach the rock codes to the polygon IDs. I have 10 rock types and say 1000 polygons (many polygons consist of the same rock type). I also have 4000 geochemical data points scattered across these polygons. I need to match the rock type with the geochemical data points but whatever i try the 'update column' gives me a column of zeros.

Comment: Have you got the field set to the correct data type that you are trying to insert into it? For example, if you are trying to update the field with text then it must be a character column.

Comment: Thank you Tom, changing the column to 'character' allowed me to add the text data. Problem solved.